# How does Jesus describe God in the Gospels

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, new-testament

How did Jesus explain the nature of God in the NT narratives ? Please cite only the relevant verses where Jesus himself describes the nature of God.

I wanted to again clarify , that I am interested in Jesus's sayings  firsthand and not someone else interpreting it what he said.

Comment: @NotMyWill- but GodsWillBe done: Please clarify what you mean by "nature." Do you mean inherent characteristics (φύσις) as opposed to accidents? Or, do you mean the very essence (οὐσία) of God?

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 All aspects of nature of God , as described by Jesus himself firsthand and not someone else interpreting it.

Comment: this looks like a List Question

Comment: @NotMyWill- but GodsWillBe done: Again, what do you mean by "nature"? Repeating the very word I am asking you to clarify is not clarification.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 all aspects of nature of God , you even have a tag for it.

Comment: @NotMyWill- but GodsWillBe done: Since you don't wish to clarify what you mean by "nature," I VTC.

Comment: Jesus spends half the gospels describing God in some way or another.

Comment: To say that you won't allow anyone else's words but Jesus is to disqualify the Biblical account. The Bible we have was recorded by people who, if they so chose, could have changed the words they ascribed to Jesus. One could make a good case against such a claim, but to the point: if you disallow all the Christian writings except those passages that say "Jesus said, '...'", then you're not going to get a complete picture and any reasoning or argumentation built on that assumption will necessarily be faulty.

Answer (score 6):

I attempted to list a few verses below where the Father character is described in detail.

> Joh 10:29  My Father, which gave them me, is greater than all; and no man is able to pluck them out of my Father's hand.

Greater than all.

> Joh 3:35  The Father loveth the Son, and hath given all things into his hand.
> Joh 3:36  He that believeth on the Son hath everlasting life: and he that believeth not the Son shall not see life; but the wrath of God abideth on him.

Loving, Saving and Wrathful.

> Luk 11:9  And I say unto you, Ask, and it shall be given you; seek, and ye shall find; knock, and it shall be opened unto you.
> Luk 11:10  For every one that asketh receiveth; and he that seeketh findeth; and to him that knocketh it shall be opened.
> Luk 11:11  If a son shall ask bread of any of you that is a father, will he give him a stone? or if he ask a fish, will he for a fish give him a serpent?
> Luk 11:12  Or if he shall ask an egg, will he offer him a scorpion?
> Luk 11:13  If ye then, being evil, know how to give good gifts unto your children: how much more shall your heavenly Father give the Holy Spirit to them that ask him?

Good and Generous.

> Joh 14:7  If ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also: and from henceforth ye know him, and have seen him.
> Joh 14:8  Philip saith unto him, Lord, shew us the Father, and it sufficeth us.
> Joh 14:9  Jesus saith unto him, Have I been so long time with you, and yet hast thou not known me, Philip? he that hath seen me hath seen the Father; and how sayest thou then, Shew us the Father?
> Joh 14:10  Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that dwelleth in me, he doeth the works.
>
> Joh 5:19  Then answered Jesus and said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, The Son can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father do: for what things soever he doeth, these also doeth the Son likewise.
> Joh 5:20  For the Father loveth the Son, and sheweth him all things that himself doeth: and he will shew him greater works than these, that ye may marvel.
> Joh 5:21  For as the Father raiseth up the dead, and quickeneth them; even so the Son quickeneth whom he will.
> Joh 5:22  For the Father judgeth no man, but hath committed all judgment unto the Son:
> Joh 5:23  That all men should honour the Son, even as they honour the Father. He that honoureth not the Son honoureth not the Father which hath sent him.

Every act of kindness, compassion, healing and deliverance which is attributed to Jesus can also be attributed to the Father. Every sermon and judgment made by Christ can likewise be attributed to the Father.

Comment: I agree and He identified God as "Father"! 38 times in Matthew alone.

Answer (score 0):

If by the word "God," you mean The Father of Jesus. Then: to see Jesus "describing" The Father you must observe Jesus working in the Gospels. In the stories and parables you can see The Father "interfering" in the lives of His children. To Philip, He said He was just like The Father. (Jo 14:9.) And also The Father is perfect (Mt 5:48) And He judges no man (Jo 5:22.)
He said no man knows The Father, except those He reveals Him to (Mt 11:27.)
The Father will give, to anyone who asks, whatsoever he wants (Lu 11:11.)
There is much more to say, but not now.

Answer (score 0):

In Mark's Gospel, Jesus draws a clear distinction between God and himself.

In [Mark 10:18](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Mark&chapter=10&verse=18), Jesus calls God "good":

> And Jesus said unto him, Why callest thou me good? there is none good but one, that is, God.

In [Mark 13:32](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Mark&chapter=13&verse=32), Jesus says that only the Father knows just when the end will come:

> But of that day and that hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels which are in heaven, neither the Son, but the Father.

In [John 8:49](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=John&chapter=8&verse=49), when Jesus tells the Jews they dishonour him, he says that he honours God:

> Jesus answered, I have not a devil; but I honour my Father, and ye do dishonour me.

In [John 10:29](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=John&chapter=10&verse=29), Jesus says God is greater than all:

> My Father, which gave them me, is greater than all; and no man is able to pluck them out of my Father's hand.

Answer (score -3):

I have one thing that comes to mind.  Before we begin you must remember the side story David and Bathsheba.  They had a son together and God said the child will not live for it would give occasion for the enemies of the LORD to blaspheme (paraphrase)

---

Jesus was asked what is the greatest commandment.  If i did not know anything out of the Hebrew bible, what would i NEED to know.

He gave them 2 commands and i believe they accurately reflect Jesus describing the nature of God.

"Love the LORD your God with all your heart, mind, body, and soul, and the second is like it, love your neighbor as yourself." - (Paraphrase)

When Jesus said this He made 2 things very clear:
First we do not understand how important it is to love our neighbors.
Second God's glory is His first concern.  Love the LORD your God with all your heart, but His concern for humanity is a runner up, Love your neighbor as yourself.

---

This might be considered a stretch and if it is :)  Sorry!  If there is typos sorry, i have not proof read my works

Comment: i don't think any situation in the old testament properly described our character of God in the way the new testament would show. they knew God by proxy through angles and moses and sometimes a prophet. citing an example from the old testament here doesn't really fit.

Comment: no offense but that is kind of silly.  "I desire mercy instead of sacrafice", "I desire obedience instead of sacrafice".  There are plenty more specific attributes about who God is.  This question had to do with Jesus but the foundation of all that Jesus taught was from the Hebrew Bible, not from some "new way."  Nothing found in the Christian canon can be said to be completely new *other than some insights into prophecy and a more complete view of the 3 in 1 God (by more complete i still mean extremely lacking)*

Comment: Even in matthew Jesus says The earth and the heaven will pass but not the smallest letter or stroke shall pass (paraphrase)

Comment: @Michael can you please explain how this answers the question? Also can you please explain "I desire mercy instead of sacrafice"